Build Android APK from VS Code Flutter
After running:
flutter build apk --release

I get these messages:

What can I do to solve this problem?

These are just version incompatibility warnings in the SDK, initially they won't cause you any problems, as you can see the APK was generated.
It is natural to have such warnings, and you won't have them once all the elements that make up your development environment are compatible and up to date
